# Equolent add object with userid

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use the Laravel 5.2 framework.

I have a Model called `template`. There are user specific layout options.

Now I want get the templates easy with

```
$template = App\Template::where('userid', Auth::user->id);
```

But if I want to add these templates I have a little problem.

```
App\Template::create(Request::all());
```

Doesnt work, because the Request has no `userid`
What is the typical way to save a new object with the userid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just merge the Request array with an array containing the user ID. Like so:

```
App\Template::create(array_merge(Request:all(), array('user_id' => Auth::user->id)));
```

Comment: Work's great. Thanks dude!
(I accept the answer in 6 minutes ;)